# Linked-in Javascript SDK : IN is undefined

Tags: javascript, web-services, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the Linked-in Javascript SDK to add their sharing functionality on a site I'm working on. I have included this code in the `<head>` section of my page, as per the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk#initialize):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key:   "API_KEY"
onLoad:    ""
authorize: true
lang:      "en_US"
</script>
```

After that, in the body of my page, I make the below call:

```
IN.API.Raw('/people/~/shares').method('POST').body(bodyContent).result(function(){});
```

However, I get the following error in chrome: `Uncaught ReferenceError: IN is not defined`.

Anybody has any idea what could be the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem: I was adding the SDK-initializing script to the `<head>` element using innerHTML. Apparently, that didn't seem like a good idea, from the error logged in the chrome console. All I had to do was directly put the script within the `<head>` element and that resolved the `IN is not defined` error.